# How to get a program's running time in Haskell

Tags: haskell, time, profiling, execution, measurement

How can I go about getting a program's running time through system time functions in Haskell? I would like to measure the execution time of a whole program and/or an individual function.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516808/writing-a-time-function-in-haskell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you don't just want to measure the total running time of your program, like so:

```
 $ time ./A
```

Then you can time a computation a number of ways in Haskell:

- [Basic timing](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Timing_computations) (e.g. as in the [timeit package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/timeit/1.0.0.0/doc/html/System-TimeIt.html))
- [Timing in cycles](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Timing_computation_in_cycles)

For more statistically sound measurement, consider

- [The Criterion package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).

Finally, in all cases, you need to think about lazy evaluation: do you want to measure the cost of fully evaluating whatever data you produce, or just to its outermost constructor?

Comment: What about compiling with `-prof` and using `+RTS -s`?

Comment: Compiling with -prof changes the characteristics of the program. Notably, the program will be much slower.

Answer (score 24):

1) If you want to benchmark something, use the [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) package.

2) If you want to time a function and are positive you have controlled for laziness as needed, then just use `Data.Time.getCurrentTime` from the [time](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) package.:

```
import Data.Time
...
   start <- getCurrentTime
   runOperation
   stop <- getCurrentTime
   print $ diffUTCTime stop start
```

A slicker packaging of the above pattern can be found in the [timeit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/timeit) package.

3) If you actually want the running time of a *program* that just happens to be written in Haskell then use your systems `time` utility.  For most POSIX systems (Mac, Linux) just run:

```
$ time ./SomeProgram
```

And it will report user, wall, and system time.

Answer (score 6):

`:set +s` is really neat if use ghci, otherwise you can use `Criterion.Measurement`, see [my answer to another question with example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22588000/1338198).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how accurate it is, but using `:set +s` in ghci will show the time and space used for subsequent computations.